# PHP call stored procedure with MSSQL_Query from SQL server 2012 return invalid value

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a PHP file which calls Stored Procedure from MSSQL. The stored procedure calculate the value and store into a temp table. When I call the stored procedure from PHP like this

```
$cmd="exec get_value ".implode(",",$parameter_arr);
$result = mssql_query("SET ANSI_NULLS ON;");
$result = mssql_query("SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;"); 
$result= mssql_query($cmd,$conn) or die("Error :".mssql_get_last_message());
```

The value return was only "::" without integer number.

When I run the stored procedure in T-Sql, it returns the correct value '02:15:00'  [T-SQL output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2S3F.jpg)

I am using PHP 5.3.3. Do I need to upgrade my php? Or why I cannot display the value correctly in PHP?

I have no control over the stored procedure. But I need to display the result into my php page. However, the result come incompletely. Some values are returning and some are not. Those value with heavy calculation in SELECT statement has problem displaying in PHP page. Like

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(INT,ETS_PhoneHours*1.0))) = 1 THEN '0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(INT,ETS_PhoneHours*1.0)) ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(INT,ETS_PhoneHours*1.0)) END + ':' 
               + CASE WHEN LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(INT,(ETS_PhoneHours*1.0 - CONVERT(INT,ETS_PhoneHours*1.0))*60) )) = 1 THEN '0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(INT,(ETS_PhoneHours*1.0 - CONVERT(INT,ETS_PhoneHours*1.0))*60) ) ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(INT,(ETS_PhoneHours*1.0 - CONVERT(INT,ETS_PhoneHours*1.0))*60) ) END + ':' 
               + CASE WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(INT,((ETS_PhoneHours*1.0 - CONVERT(INT,ETS_PhoneHours*1.0))*60 - CONVERT(INT,(ETS_PhoneHours*1.0 - CONVERT(INT,ETS_PhoneHours*1.0))*60))*60)),1,2)) = 1 THEN  '0' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(INT,((ETS_PhoneHours*1.0 - CONVERT(INT,ETS_PhoneHours*1.0))*60 - CONVERT(INT,(ETS_PhoneHours*1.0 - CONVERT(INT,ETS_PhoneHours*1.0))*60))*60)),1,2) ELSE SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(INT,((ETS_PhoneHours*1.0 - CONVERT(INT,ETS_PhoneHours*1.0))*60 - CONVERT(INT,(ETS_PhoneHours*1.0 - CONVERT(INT,ETS_PhoneHours*1.0))*60))*60)),1,2) END
      AS 'ETS_Program_Hours'
```

This will only return :: to my mssql_query. 
Anyone face the similar issue before?

Please advice. Thanks

Comment: I just need to display whether return from the stored procedure. But the php cannot display all the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use CONVERT?

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(40),ETS_PhoneHours,108) AS 'ETS_Program_Hours'
```